# Um botão booleano e menu dinâmico com jsf Programação java html primefaces jsf

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

Olá,

Eu preciso fazer um botão booleano com jsf (primefaces) e html e um menu dinâmico que um botão chama outro, só que eu não tenho ideia de como fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar? Eu comecei fazer alguma coisa, esses são os códigos

tests

```
    <br><h:outputText value="Numero da Conta:  " /> <p:inputNumber
            value="#{cadastro.numConta}"></p:inputNumber></br>

    <br><h:outputText value="Saldo:  " /> <p:inputNumber
            value="#{cadastro.saldo}"></p:inputNumber></br>

    <br><h:outputText value="Nome:  " /> <p:inputText
            value="#{cadastro.nome}" /></br>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="msgs" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:12px" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputText value="Confirmar cadastramento: " />
        <p:selectBooleanButton id="Nknow" onLabel="Sim" offLabel="Não">
            <p:ajax update="msgs" listener="#{selectBooleanView.addMessage()}"/>
        </p:selectBooleanButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
     <p:commandButton  value="Cadastrar"  icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />
</h:form>
```

Classe:

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.menu;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class SelectBooleanView {

    private boolean value1;   
    private boolean value2;
    public int dia1;
    public int dia2;

    public boolean isValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(boolean value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public boolean isValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(boolean value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public void addMessage() {
        String summary = value2 ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(summary));
    }
}
```

Outra:

```
package classes.menu;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;


@ManagedBean
public class Cadastro {
    public String nome;
    public int numAge;
    public int numConta;
    public int getNumConta() {
        return numConta;
    }

    public void setNumConta(int numConta) {
        this.numConta = numConta;
    }

    public int getNumAge() {
        return numAge;
    }

    public void setNumAge(int numAge) {
        this.numAge = numAge;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public double saldo;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como seria o menu? Explique mais detalhadamente

Comment: Eu preciso de um menu que quando aperta o Botão de Opção apareça as opções de Cadastramento,Saque e Depósito e vai para a página da opção escolhida .

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, te recomendo olhar o `tabView` do primefaces, acredito que lhe será útil, O link [Aqui](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml)

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, qualquer coisa colto aqui. Obrigada

Comment: Consegui de outro jeito, apenas colocando no url o caminho do arquivo dos outros menu. Obrigada